# Replacing all white spaces with commas in a 46MB text file

Tags: macos, text-editing, textmate

How long should replacing all white spaces with commas take in my 46MB text file using a simple text editor such as textmate on Mac?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Have you tried it yourself? If yes, do you think it's taking too long?

Comment: Should be near instantaneous, if not instant...

Comment: This is 46MB... I dunno about textmate, but a lot of text editors choke on files that large, textmate may not be working 100% properly.

Comment: @nimble @studiohack It is actually running since 20 minutes. That's why I'm asking. I just need some quick tip how this is usually done. Maybe some other text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` from Terminal this would take a few seconds:

```
sed -i "s/ /,/g" bigfile
```

(In my test, 565786 spaces in a 46 MB binary file were replaced in 2.1 seconds.)

Vim works too (`:%s/ /,/g`) but was a little slower.

Edit: `s/[[:space:]]/,/g` to include tabs (which, I assume, you meant by "whitespace")